# Drupal JSONAPI date range date range

Tags: drupal, fetch, headless, json-api, headless-cms

I followed the documentation on [filtering](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/filtering).
Used the following code in order to fetch date range data.

&filter[datefilter][condition][path]=field_date&filter[datefilter][condition][operator]=>=&filter[datefilter][condition][value]=${fiscal_year_start}&filter[datefilter][condition][path]=field_date&filter[datefilter][condition][operator]=<=&filter[datefilter][condition][value]=${fiscal_year_end}

It fetches the second filter condition only. It would be great if anyone can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved once I change the second condition filter name [datefilter] to a different name.